# fflush(stdout) в QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Задача такова:
Существует консольное приложение, осуществляющее некоторое действие (в частности: копирование файла с сохранением времени доступа). Для данного приложения необходимо реализовать графический интерфейс. Решил реализовывать путем простого создания дочернего процесса и передачи ему необходимых аргументов из текстовых полей, и копирования данных из stdout процесса в свое текстовое поле. Данный подход дал желаемый результат за исключением маленькой детали:

Приложение выводит в консоль прогресс бар и возможно ошибки, если произошли. пример:

```
>App copy setup.ini test\setup.ini
18483968:18483968 bytes copied (100.000000%)
```

Обновление прогресс бара выглядит примерно так:

```
printf("\r%d:%d bytes copied (%f%%)", count, total, count / total)) * 100));
fflush(stdout);
```

Данный участок кода вызывается с некоторой периодичностью и создает видимость печати статуса в одной строке, что прекрасно работает в консоли. Однако при вызове из графической оболочки, в свое текстовое поле я получаю данные следующего характера:

```
204800:18483968 bytes copied (1.107987%)
409600:18483968 bytes copied (2.215974%)
........................................
18432000:18483968 bytes copied (99.718849%)
18483968:18483968 bytes copied (100.000000%)
```

Данные результаты наталкивают меня на мысль, что для процесса, запущенного с помощью QT fflush(stdout) не создает такого-же эффекта, как с консолью. Существует ли способ реализовать необходимое поведение в QT?

Код, считывающий stdout:

```
void Process::update_stdout()
{
    _stdout = QString(_process->readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

Код, осуществляющий вызов процесса:

```
void StartProcess(Process &process, const QString &prog, const QStringList 
&args, QTextEdit *text_edit_for_stdout)
{
    process.raw_process()->start(prog, args);
    process.raw_process()->waitForStarted(-1);
    do
    {
        process.raw_process()->waitForFinished(100);
    }
    while (process.raw_process()->state() == QProcess::Running);

    text_edit_for_stdout->clear();
    text_edit_for_stdout->setText(process.get_stdout());

    ShowMessageBox("Action finished");
}
```

Comment: `_stdout = QString(_process->readAllStandardOutput());`?

Comment: Обновил, результат не изменился

Comment: Текстовое поле это случайно не `QTextEdit`?

Comment: Именно QTextEdit

Comment: Тогда [вот](https://forum.qt.io/topic/85162/qtextedit-and-carriage-return-r-character). Некие люди на форуме говорят что `QTextEdit` заменяет `\r` на `\n`.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вопрос именно о том, чтобы получать стандартный вывод процесса "кусочками", после каждого `fflush`, а не весь целиком в самом конце. Т.е. вопрос вообще не об эффекте `\r` в консоли.

Comment: Так а что же вы хотели? Вы запускаете процесс, **ждете его полного завершения** и только после завершения читаете весь выход. О каком `fflush` вообще может идти речь в такой ситуации? Как вы и просили, вы получаете полный вывод процесса, от начала до конца. Почему вы ожидали чего-то другого? Если вы хотите отслеживать прогресс вашего процесса, то читать выход надо было постоянно в процессе его работы, а не после завершения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, исправив код обновления строки состояния:

Убрал этот код:

```
printf("\r%d:%d bytes copied (%f%%)", count, total, count / total)) * 100));
fflush(stdout);
```

Вместо него добавил этот:

```
std::cout.clear();
std::cout << std::flush << std::fixed << "\r" << count<< ":" << total<< " bytes copied (" << (double)(((double)((double)count/ (double)total)) * 100) << "%)";
```